# Error fetching swift post variables

Tags: ios, swift

i have created a HTTP POST request in swift ios. when i fetch a post variables in php file, it is showing blank, i am not getting a variable value. below my swift code, look it.

```
var dataString = "name=john&type=student"

var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()

request.URL = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com/example.php")

var postString = (dataString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

request.HTTPBody = postString

var connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)

func connection(didReceiveResponse: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!) {
    //New request so we need to clear the data object
    println(response)
}
```

Php code:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['name'];
?>
```

Anyone can suggest what should i do for getting a variables value. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json`

Comment: Actually, it __does__ answer the question.  The problem is that he's sending data as the body in x-www-form-urlencoded format and calling it JSON.  Since he's telling PHP it's JSON, it's not being decoded as POST parameters into _POST.