# Alamofire post seen as get on localhost

Tags: php, swift, post, get, alamofire

My previously working POST calls to the server stopped working and are interpreted as GET calls when I migrated to Alamofire 3 on iOS 9 with Swift.

I've compressed things to a pretty small test case that shows the problem.  The PHP just prints out the parameters received:

```
$type = "NONE";
if (isset($_POST['a'])) {
  $a = $_POST['a'];
  $type = "POST";
} else {
  $a = $_GET['a'];
  $type = "GET";
}

$result = array("a" => $a, "b" => "something", "t" => $type);
echo(json_encode($result));
```

The client Swift code responds to button actions for the GET and POST calls:

```
    @IBAction func localGet(sender: AnyObject) {
      print("Local Get")
      let postsEndpoint : String = "http://localhost/~paris/small.php?a=getting"
      Alamofire.request(.GET, postsEndpoint, parameters : nil, encoding : .JSON)
        .responseJSON { response in
            guard response.result.error == nil else {
                print("error calling localhost GET")
                return
            }
            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
      }
    }


    @IBAction func localPost(sender: AnyObject) {
      print("Local Post")        
      let postsEndpoint : String = "http://localhost/~paris/small.php"
      let newPost = ["title" : "First Post", "body" : "I is first", " userId" : 1, "a" : "posting"]
      Alamofire.request(.POST, postsEndpoint, parameters : newPost, encoding : .JSON)
        .responseJSON { response in
            guard response.result.error == nil else {
                print("error calling localhost POST")
                return
            }
            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
      }
    }
```

Here is some output from the code, which shows how both cases as seen as GET and so the attempt at POST loses the parameter passed in:

```
Local Get
JSON: {
    a = getting;
    b = something;
    t = GET;
}
Local Post
JSON: {
    a = "<null>";
    b = something;
    t = GET;
}
```

I saw a posting that it was [a GoDaddy problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30700738/post-request-detected-as-get-on-godaddy-servers-with-alamofire) but I'm using a localhost on my computer.  I had also tried to [change the content-type to urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298793/error-fetching-swift-post-variables) based on another post but that didn't work (so I omitted the code here for clarity).

I'm at a loss as to what to try.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: GET uses the URL parameter, but POST sends your dictionary in the post *body*. I'm not a PHP expert so I may be saying stupid but it looks like you're not handling that. :)

Comment: That's what I believe I'm doing: using the URL for the GET and a dictionary to be included in the body for the POST.  Looking at the server script may be good advice although I've always used the $_POST variable that is automatically populated with key-value pairs of the POST'ed parameters.  Here, the very first thing I do is to check if the $_POST['a'] is defined, which should be (by the contrived nature of the test script). I feel relatively confident about this script but I'm no PHP guru, either. I'm just a bit more suspicious of the shifting Swift ecosystem than I am of the PHP world...